# MemoryError when importing json in system python

Tags: apt, package-management, python

When I enter the system python3.6 and import json, I get the following stack trace:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from .encoder import JSONEncoder
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 764, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 833, in get_data
MemoryError
```

This is odd to me because I have 24 Gigs of RAM.

When I use my default work Python (miniconda) and `import` JSON it works fine:

```
Python 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:51:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>>
```

My main issue with the system default Python json failing to load is that it prevents a full update with `sudo apt update`.

```
Fetched 252 kB in 3s (95.0 kB/s)    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
  File "/usr/lib/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 4, in <module>
    import json
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from .encoder import JSONEncoder
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 764, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 833, in get_data
MemoryError
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Thank you for your help!